# Android - last modification of SharedPreference

Tags: android, date, sharedpreferences, last-modified

Is there a way to find that out?

My idea was to read last modification date of the settings file, but as far as I know, that's not possible on an unrooted phone...

Answer (score 0):

Instantly an idea came to my mind but I am not sure will that be any good one to implement. While committing the `SharedPreference` always update a key say `last_modified` with `System.currentTimeMillis()`. If your application have any final commit (say you commit any data everytime on `onDestroy` method) then you can only save the `last_modified` then. Else you have to update it everytime. That is definitely an overhead.

Comment: i had the idea myself and wouldn't mind implementing that, if I would ONLY use my PreferenceActivity, but I also have some variables in my SharedPreferences that are set somewhere in code... I want to avoid to use a custom function that always sets the last_modified date as well, because I want to be sure to miss no point in my code... I need the last modification date because I'm backing up my database/settings and I only want to do that, if data was modified...

Comment: you can easily create a wrappcer class and instead of calling commit of SharedPreference you can call commit of your wrapper class. and in the commit method you can stoe the last_modified..no big issue

Comment: I know... Would be no big deal... If it would be a new project and not a project I'm working on for a year now... But I will end up in doing this... I replacing everything in the project with my wrapper function or class... Just thought, before doing that, I ask if someone has a better and easier idea...